# Print line for word found in file in directory

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal

Hello  i am using this line

```
find ./ -iname *txt | xargs grep "ququ" -sl>holis.txt
```

To find "ququ" text in a txt file and then write the file name that does contain such word in the txt file, holis.txt,

My question is how can i write the line that contains such character and also the previous line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i write the line that contains such character and also the previous line

Use `-B1`.

For example:

```
$ seq 10 >file
$ grep -B1 5 file
4
5
```

If you want to include the file's name, that add `-H`:

```
$ grep -HB1 5 file
file-4
file:5
```

#### Combined with `find`

Assuming that you have either GNU `find` or a modern BSD `find`, then your complete command can be simplified to:

```
find ./ -iname '*txt' -exec grep -HB1 "ququ" {} + >holis.txt
```